# make assignment operator work on declaration

Tags: c++, c++14, immutability

I was trying to make an immutable Angle class (shown below). `Angle z = 42;` doesn't work. How do I make it work? Sample:

```
  Angle a(1); // works
  Angle b; b = 2; // works
  Angle c {25}; // works
  Angle d {26.0}; // works
  Angle e = 27.0; // doesn't compile -- why not?
  auto f = Angle(28.0); // works
```

Source:

```
  class Angle {
      double _angle;

    public:
      explicit Angle(double value) noexcept : _angle(wrap0To2Pi(value)) {}
      Angle() = default;
      Angle(const Angle& angle) noexcept : _angle(angle._angle) {}
      Angle(const Angle&& angle) noexcept : _angle(angle._angle) {}

      operator double() const { return _angle; }

      Angle& operator=(const Angle& f) noexcept { _angle = f._angle; return *this; }
      Angle& operator=(double t) { _angle = wrap0To2Pi(t); return *this; }

      Angle operator+(Angle value) const { return Angle(_angle + value._angle); }
      Angle operator-(Angle value) const { return Angle(_angle - value._angle); }
      Angle operator*(Angle value) const { return Angle(_angle * value._angle); }

      constexpr static double DEFAULT_ANGLE_TOLERANCE = 0.0001;
      bool equals(Angle value, double tolerance = DEFAULT_ANGLE_TOLERANCE) const; // needs to wrap

      bool operator==(Angle value) const { return equals(value); }
      bool operator!=(Angle value) const { return !equals(value); }
      ...
```

Anything else I should change here? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hint 1. It isn't an assignment operator. Hint 2. Look into `explicit`.

Comment: the `explicit` on your first constructor disallows this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a definition of the form

```
Angle e = 27.0;
```

there is only initialization, no assignment. This will attempt to call a constructor of `Angle` that will accept the `double` argument. However, since you've marked the `Angle(double)` constructor `explicit`, you cannot perform this conversion with this syntax.

If you want this to work, remove the `explicit` keyword.

Comment: So when do I need to use `explicit`?

Comment: @Brannon when you don't want this form of initialization to work.